# CSS percentage widths and heights and resolution problems

Tags: css, screen-resolution, units-of-measurement

I need my application run in multiple screen resolutions.
Currently I have specified all the dimensions in percentage (%) instead of pixels (px) so that it will automatically re-size with the screen.

Which would be the more reliable unit of measurement for specifying dimensions on my webpage: Pixels (or EM) or Percentage

Comment: "Reliable" depends on the structure and requirements of your layout.

Comment: I think the biggest issue here is that responsive webdesign should be tackled by providing a separate set of css rules for each resolution, and not some master css file that will incorporate all resolutions (or not which is more likely)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [Responsive Webdesign](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries) you really should be leveraging [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Personally I prefer pixels because they give me more control, and I can reliably know the exact dimensions of each element. With media queries you can also set new styles based on the screen resolution.

Percentages give you a nice responsive feel, but can be much more difficult to ensure you're layout is not junked by each level of resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Both approaches are "reliable".  However, if you are looking for auto-resizing, percentages is the way to go.  If you do not want the elements to resize based on the size of the window, pixels would a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Percentage always applies to a percentage of the parent element, while pixels are always fixed. Percentages are more accessible especially on smaller monitors *however* you will run into problems with things line breaking at the wrong times and the like. For example, if you have a 50px image and 100px wide line of text, and you want the items on the same line, specify a 150px width, because if you specify a percent, they may appear right on your monitor but not others.