# Getting a 500px wide design to render correctly on different screen sizes

Tags: css, mobile, cross-browser, responsive-design, mobile-safari

I have a website with all content centered. The content has a width of `500px`.

I'm only concerned about the content (the 500px) to be visible, how much of the gutter doesn't matter.

For desktop displays I have the following CSS rules:

```
margin: 0 auto;
width: 500px;
```

**What should be applied so that the content area gets displayed in it's entirety on as many screen sizes as possible (i.e. as small as 320px)?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998850/css-percentage-widths-and-heights-and-resolution-problems

Comment: What do you mean, that I have to go with media queries?

Answer (score 0):

to support different screen sizes you should use percentage, not pixel. But in case you are more comfortable using fixed width (using pixel) you can use media queries to achieve that.

```
.container {  //start with the smallest screen width
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {  // 640px
    .container {
        width: 500px;
    }
}
```

But I do recommend you to use percentage instead of pixel. Hope you find this useful.